# How to scrape a style attribute associated with a class from html

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am using simple_html_dom scraping class for this.

I have a html element with a class and I want to scrape the background-color attribute for this class. How do I achieve this?

```
<div class="identifier"></div>
```

I can pick up the div via:

```
$output = $html->find('.identifier');
```

But the style rules for the identifier class is in the style sheet.

Comment: You can get the link of the css using simple_html_dom, then download it and use some css parser like [PHP-CSS-Parser](https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser) (or maybe there's another better one) to get what you want... If it's the only case you have to parse css, then you can use regex instead...

Comment: That is what I am doing. Feel free to put that as the answer. I wondered if there was an easier way. Do you know what regex I would need to match the backgroundcolor attribute of this in the stylesheet: .identifier {   background-color: #114A9F;  }

Comment: you want to check if `background-color` has the value `#114A9F`, or to retrieve that value ?

Comment: Nevere mind, I posted the two situations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the link of the css using simple_html_dom, then download it and use some css parser like [PHP-CSS-Parser](https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser) (or maybe there's another better one) to get what you want...

If it's the only case you have to parse css, then you can use regex instead...

**Example**

To get the `background-color` value from `.identifier { background-color: #114A9F; }`, you can use this pattern:

```
\.identifier\s*{[^}]+background-color\s*:\s*([^;]+)
```

<kbd>[Live DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sU3fN5)</kbd>

However to match that exact value, use this pattern instead:

```
\.identifier\s*{[^}]*background-color\s*:\s*#114A9F;
```

<kbd>[Live DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zL5aW2)</kbd>